# Remove duplicate keeping the last occurance of value in resultant pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

Im new to pyspark dataframes,I have input dataframe in below format :

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | CAR1_V1 |
| 2 | CAR1_V2 |
| 3 | CAR1_V3 |
| 4 | CAR2_V1 |
| 5 | CAR2_V2 |
| 6 | CAR3_V1 |
| 7 | CAR3_V1 |

Now I need to convert it in below format :

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | CAR1_V3 |
| 5 | CAR2_V2 |
| 7 | CAR3_V1 |

Not only duplicates need to remove also have to keep the last occurance of values(like data between underscore have to consider separately.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efPjB.png)

Comment: Could you please provider some example data (input and expected output)?

Comment: Please add the data to the question and format it as table. At the moment, it's quite hard to figure out what you are trying to achieve

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Besides that, its (at least for me) still unclear how the output is calculated. Should the data be parsed?

Comment: Added data in a tabular format, Not only duplicates need to remove also have to keep the last occurance of values (like data between underscore have to consider separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result can be achieved in 4 steps:

- Split the column `value` in two parts (lines 3-5)
- Group by the first part of `value` (line 6)
- Take the maximum version and the `id` and `value` that belongs to this version using [max_by](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/sql/index.html#max_by) (line 7)
- Optional: Drop the intermediate columns and sort the result (lines 8 and 9)

```pyton
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('split', F.split('value', '_'))\
    .withColumn('value_part1', F.col('split')[0]) \
    .withColumn('version', F.col('split')[1]) \
    .groupBy('value_part1') \
    .agg(F.expr('max(version)'), F.expr('max_by(value, version) as value'), F.expr('max_by(id, version) as id')) \
    .select('id', 'value') \
    .orderBy('id') \
    .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-------+
| id|  value|
+---+-------+
|  3|CAR1_V3|
|  5|CAR2_V2|
|  7|CAR3_V2|
+---+-------+
```

Note: I assume that the version part of `value` is unique.